# How can I access a low-level client from a Boto 3 resource instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

For example, I have this code:

```
import boto3

ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')

# Where is the client???
```

Do I need to call `boto3.client('ec2')` or is there another way?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Every resource object has a special attribute called `meta`, which is a Python dict containing information about the service, access to the low-level client, and sometimes the lazy-loaded cached attributes of the resource. You can access it like so:

```
client = ec2.meta.client

response = client.reboot_instances(InstanceIds=[...])
```

This is particularly useful if you created the resource using custom parameters which you don't want to have to keep track of for later:

```
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2', region_name='us-west-2')

# This client is now a US-West-2 client
client = ec2.meta.client
```

As always, be sure to check out the [official documentation](http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/). **Note**: this interface changed in [boto3#45](https://github.com/boto/boto3/pull/45). Previously `meta` was a `dict`.